# VMware vcenter client unable to log in

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-server, vmware-vcenter

I restarted our DC this morning and now we are unable to log into the client to see all the VM'S the credentials are correct but it says there wrong...  Did I need to do something before rebooting and how do I fix it...

Comment: Presumably this is via AD/LDAP credentials? so have you tried using local/SSO credentials such as your administrator@system-domain/administrator@vsphere.local account? you'll need that to be able to login anyway to check the AD/LDAP credentials are set correctly.

Comment: I have not I will try that when I get back to that network, and yes it is using AD/LDAP

Answer (score 0):

I would restart the vcenter services on your Windows box now that the DC is back up and running before going any further.